# Create list or view that show which customers are shared with other users

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm new to Dynamic CRM.

I want to create view or list that shows which all customers are shared with which user and who is the owner of that customer.

Is there any way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to set up a view of contacts (or accounts depending which you are calling "customers") and their respective owners.  Putting the users who have been shared to in a view is not as simple because there is no limit to the number of people who can be shared to (there is a 1:N relationship of record to shares, and views cannot display a list of items on the N side of a relationship).

For example, if you want to set up a personal view of contacts and their owners, go to Advanced Find, choose "Contacts" in the Look for box, then hit edit columns and add the "Owner" field.  Then just save as the view and name it whatever you want.  (System wide views work similar, but you create it through customizations instead of Advanced Find).

Comment: My main requirement is to find the customers shared with other user. Is there any way to do it in C#??

Comment: One way of doing this is to set a bool field "shared" on the customer and then write a plugin that sets that bool to true when you share the record and also set the bool to false when all are unshared (check number of shared users on unshare).
This will of course only give you newly shared so you need to update the bool of all customers that are currently shared.

Comment: you will also need to create a text field where you concatenate the names of the users who were the target of the share if you need to display that information.